# Linking to specific place in apps

Tags: android, react-native

How to linking to specific place in my React-native app I try using deep linking but link like this app://pleace in others app dosen't work, but this

```
android:scheme="http"
android:host="www.example.com"
```

it's work, code in AndroidManifest

```
<intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
  <data android:scheme="app"
              android:host="pleace"/>
</intent-filter>
```